# How to extract latest articles from DBLP

Tags: php, xml, semantics

I need to extract the latest articles from a `DBLP`

The description and all the fields of all elements can be found at:

http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.dtd

The help file is located at:

http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/docu/dblpxml.pdf

SO, you have a API, you do a GET request, by Year, and you get a JSON document;

I would like to get a JSON doc with the articles from today;

But I don't know how to make the GET request using the `mdate` attribute;

This is the structure of a article:

```
<article key="journals/cacm/Szalay08"
mdate="2008-11-03">
<author>Alexander S. Szalay</author>
<title>Jim Gray, astronomer.</title>
<pages>58-65</pages>
<year>2008</year>
<volume>51</volume>
<journal>Commun. ACM</journal>
<number>11</number>
<ee>http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/
1400214.1400231</ee>
<url>db/journals/cacm/
cacm51.html#Szalay08</url>
</article>
```

I tryed this `http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/acta/BayerM72` and got:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dblp>
<article key="journals/acta/BayerM72"
mdate="2003-11-25">
<author>Rudolf Bayer</author>
<author>Edward M. McCreight</author>
<title>Organization and Maintenance
of Large Ordered Indices</title>
...
</article>
</dblp>
```

I need to extract all the latest articles, by using the fields `mdate`.

This is a article about various requests: http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/docu/dblpxmlreq.pdf

the php code:

```
<pre>
    <?php
    $url = 'http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/';
    $key = 'journals/acta/BayerM72';
    $content = file_get_contents($url . $key);
    echo $content;
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: How do you define the 'latest articles'? The example you have here will retrieve just one article. Do you expect to retrieve key by key like this, or search the entire XML database?

Comment: True, i extract just one article. I need to search the entire db, and the key should be `mdate`

Comment: I was going to have a punt at this, since it's a relatively straightforward exercise in reading an XML file. The problem, however, is wider than it appears. The API doesn't appear to provide the sort of search you want. Searching 1.3Gb of XML online is  non-starter - it'll take far too long. Searching it locally will also be too slow for most applications. This implies that you, perhaps, need to import the XML file into a database and use that to index and search. I suggest you refine the question to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you can do and what you need help with.

Comment: It's very simple actually; You have a API, you do a GET request, by Year, and you get a JSON document; I would like to get a JSON doc with the articles from today; But I don't know how to make the GET request using the `mdate` attribute;

Comment: No where on the documentation does it say you can request articles by date. I would e-mail the site admin and make a feature request.

Comment: Just a quick note: you keep saying "you do a GET request and you get a JSON document" except that these are XML documents; JSON is entirely different. Knowing the right terminology may help you find a solution... but after skimming the DBLP API it really looks like they expect you to download the whole XML document and parse it yourself. Maybe you can do this once a day and have an indexed version you can use the rest of that day?

Comment: I think this is a solved problem. Someone has already created [RSS feeds from DBLP](http://www.bpiwowar.net/software/making-an-rss-feed-from-dblp-2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parse xml there are [XML Parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) and [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). XML Parser and XMLReader are used for big file, SimpleXML - for small files (<1Mb).

```
function startElement($parser, $tag, $attrs) {
    global $articles, $isArticle, $i, $globTag;
    $globTag = $tag;
    if ($tag == 'article') {
        $isArticle = true;
        if (isset ( $attrs ['mdate'] )) {
            // add date from attribute in article
            $articles [$i] ['mdate'] = $attrs ['mdate'];
        }
    }
}
function endElement($parser, $tag) {
    global $articles, $isArticle, $i, $globTag;
    if ($tag == 'article') {
        $isArticle = false;
        ++ $i;
    }
}
function getElement($parser, $data) {
    global $articles, $isArticle, $i, $globTag;
    if ($isArticle) {
        $articles [$i] = $articles [$i] + [ 
                $globTag => $data 
        ];
    }
}
global $articles, $isArticle, $i, $globTag;
$articles = [ ];
$i = 0;
$isArticle = false;
$url = 'http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/';
$key = 'journals/acta/BayerM72';
$url .= $key;
$parser = xml_parser_create ();

xml_set_element_handler ( $parser, "startElement", "endElement" );
xml_set_character_data_handler ( $parser, 'getElement' );
xml_parser_set_option ( $parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false );

$file = fopen ( $url, 'rb' );
if ($file === false) {
    die ( "File isnt!!" );
}
$clasterSize = 8192;

while ( $data = fread ( $file, $clasterSize ) ) {
    if (! xml_parse ( $parser, $data, feof ( $file ) )) {
        die ( sprintf ( "XML error: %s at line %d", xml_error_string ( xml_get_error_code ( $parser ) ), xml_get_current_line_number ( $parser ) ) );
    }
}
xml_parser_free ( $parser );
fclose ( $file );
```

This is example in XML Parser.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/';
    $key = 'journals/acta/BayerM72';
    $content = file_get_contents($url . $key);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

/* Search for <dblp><article> */
$result = $xml->xpath('/dblp/article');
// $result is  an array of SimpleXMLElement objects
   var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

There is SimpleXML example. You get  an array of SimpleXMLElement objects in result. Look a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to get SimpleXMLElement attributes `SimpleXMLElement->attributes();`.

Comment: i am not interested in parsing a 1.3 gb file, i need to get the data using the api

Comment: You will get all articls in array $articles with date. You can use  SimpleXML (load file in memory)

Comment: i have done this and it takes 15 minutes to parse the file; to download the dblp file, and then extract it, and then parse it, it is not ok

Comment: Can you told size of the file?

Answer (score 1):

If the API doesn't offer a clean way to get updates, you'll have to cache the document and extract the articles from the changes.

DBLP2RSS, a project that creates RSS feeds from DBLP does this with a [shell script](https://github.com/bpiwowar/dblp2rss/blob/master/dblp-get-pubs):

```
#!/bin/sh

id="$1"
name="$2"
cache="$3"

test -d "$cache" || exit 1

curlit() {
    in-dcs && curl --proxy wwwcache.dcs.gla.ac.uk:8080 "$@" || curl --proxy "" "$@"
}

prefix="http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex"

echo "<dblp-content name=\"$1\">"
curlit "http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/$id/index.html" 2> /dev/null | tidy -n -asxml 2> /dev/null | xml sel -N html=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml -t  -m '//html:a' -v '@href' -n | grep "^$name" | while read path; do 
    # Should cache here
    cachefile="$cache/$id/$path"

    if ! test -f "$cachefile"; then
    mkdir -p "$(dirname $cachefile)"
    curlit "http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/$id/$path" 2> /dev/null | tidy -n -asxml 2> /dev/null >  $cachefile
    echo "Got $cachefile"

    fi
    cat "$cachefile" | xml sel -N html=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml -t  -m '//html:a' -v '@href' -n | egrep '^'"$prefix"'.*\.xml$' | sed -e 's#^'"$prefix"/'#<dblpkey>#' -e 's/\.xml$/<\/dblpkey>/'

done 

echo "</dblp-content>"
```

This doesn't get the articles, but you could take the same approach.